# "Implicit super constructor character() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor." Error

Tags: java, undefined

So I have a class called character(), and my second class ChooseCharacterGUI() extends that class, but when I try to initialize ChooseCharacterGUI() to create the application I get the error "Implicit super constructor character() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor."

This is the ChooseCharacterGUI() class.

```
public class ChooseCharacterGUI extends character {

final String CharacterChoice;
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel ChooseCharacterMenu;
private JPanel Home;


// Launches  application.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ChooseCharacterGUI window = new ChooseCharacterGUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

//Creates application 
public ChooseCharacterGUI() {
    initialize();
}
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? thanks.

Comment: By invoking another constructor, as the error message suggests.

Comment: It seems that you character class does not have a default constructor, and you should explicitly call it's constructor in constructor of derived class

Comment: Your `character` class has no non-argument constructor, so you need to call the provided constructor explicitly.

Comment: There are at least 3 ways to fix it. (1) By writing a constructor for `character` with no arguments, (2) By writing a constructor for `ChooseCharacterGUI` that invokes a constructor of `character`, (3) by removing the words `extends character`. It is difficult to know without more information which is the right thing to do.

Comment: This is a common "Java newbie" problem; see link.  The only other thing to add is that naming a class `character` is a Java style violation.  But don't change it to `Character` because that is a standard class name ... and "borrowing" can lead to readability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `character` class has a parameterised constructor and no default constructor. E.g.

```
class character {
     public character(String someargument) { ... }
}
```

So your CharacterGUI class needs to have in its default constructor a call to the parameterised constructor of the super class. E.g.

```
class CharacterGUI {
     public CharacterGUI() {
         super("somedefaultvalue");
     }
}
```

Perhaps another concern is that your super class has a lowercase first letter, which is confusing, and you're inheriting this in the class which also has the main function. This code might need a bit of refactoring when you've got it working.

Comment: This is the code from my character class - `public character (String iName, String iGender){` I just added this code to my ChooseCharacterGUI() constructor and it seems to have worked -  `public ChooseCharacterGUI() {
  super("test", "Male");
  initialize();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Every class you write must have a constructor, and every constructor must invoke super.  If you don't write a constructor, Java generates one with no arguments that does nothing but call `super()`.  If you write a constructor but don't have a super call, Java inserts an invisible `super()` at the top.  So if either of these automatic things is happening and the super class doesn't have a no-args constructor (called a default constructor), you get this error.

So your `character` class must not have a default constructor.  Either write one, or in your `CharacterGUI` class, call whatever `character` constructor you have.

I strongly suspect that you don't actually want to have `CharacterGUI` extend `character` though.  And also, by convention, `character` should be capitalized.